# Use value of <F-USER> from fail2ban regex

Tags: ssh, debian, fail2ban

I am trying to send e-mail to me and user that someone tried to login to their ssh and failed - the IP got banned. But I don't understand how can I use the  variable in the e-mail I am trying to send.

Sendmail is set up correctly as the e-mails are being sent without problem.

Here is my jail.local config

```
[sshd]
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
action  = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines-ssh[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
```

And here is my  action.d/sendmail-whois-lines-ssh.conf

```
[INCLUDES]

before = sendmail-common.conf
         helpers-common.conf

[Definition]

norestored = 1
actionban = ( printf %%b "Subject: [Fail2Ban] <name>: banned <ip> from <fq-hostname>
            Date: `LC_ALL=C date +"%%a, %%d %%h %%Y %%T %%z"`
            From: <sendername> <<sender>>
            To: <dest>, <F-USER>@mydomain.cz\n
            Hi,\n
            The IP <ip> has just been banned by Fail2Ban after
            <failures> attempts against <name>.\n\n
            Here is more information about <ip> :\n
            `/usr/bin/whois <ip> || echo missing whois program`\n\n
            Lines containing failures of <ip>\n";
            %(_grep_logs)s;
            printf %%b "\n
            Regards,\n
            Fail2Ban" ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f <sender>.mydomain.cz <dest> <F-USER>@mydomain.cz

[Init]
name = default
logpath = /dev/null
```

The e-mail sent to me is fine, because  is taken correctly from configuration, but <F-USER> has no value so it is being sent to @mydomain.cz

How can I get the value so I am able to send the e-mail to user ?

**EDIT**
The regex getting hit on SSH is this one:

```
^pam_unix\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;\s*logname=\S*\s*uid=\d*\s*euid=\d*\s*tty=\S*\s*ruser=<F-USER>\S*</F-USER>\s*rhost=<HOST>\s.*%(__suff)s$
```

Comment: That does not matter in this context, actually the <F-USER> is empty so if the e-mail is not being sent either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to send e-mail to me and user that someone tried to login to their ssh and failed

I have few doubts related to this approach, for instance by certain "vulnerability" possibly introduced thereby - RE `<F-USER>\S*</F-USER>` would match anything up to first space, so for example if matched "username" will be `someone@example.com,test` your mail will be also sent to `someone@example.com`, which may be not the user of your domain.
I could also imagine another scenarios since you're trying to use foreign input (from log) in the mail action - so better ensure this is not affected by some injection possibility (also note [GHSA-m985-3f3v-cwmm](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/security/advisories/GHSA-m985-3f3v-cwmm) for example).

> The regex getting hit on SSH is this one ...

The failregex must also contain `<F-USER>...</F-USER>` in order to capture the value that will be stored as user name and it must match something.

[Here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/8f83242c25a957d34478e9604600066695be7998/config/filter.d/sshd.conf#L54) is an example how it looks in current version (note it is not a failure RE due to `<F-NOFAIL>` tag, it's just a helper to find IP for messages without IP, see [issues/3189#issuecomment-999571654](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/3189#issuecomment-999571654) for details).

Thereby `<F-ALT_USER>` is an alternative user name and will store it to `F-USER` captured group in ticket, if part `<F-USER>...</F-USER>` would match empty value.

Maybe (like in issues/3189 above) you also have wrong backend, so switching to `systemd` would help you to match it using another sshd-regex.

Related to your regexp, it can be changed like here (back-ported from current sshd-filter):

```
- ^pam_unix\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;\s*logname=\S*\s*uid=\d*\s*euid=\d*\s*tty=\S*\s*ruser=<F-USER>\S*</F-USER>\s*rhost=<HOST>\s.*%(__suff)s$
+ ^pam_unix\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;(?:\s+(?:(?:logname|e?uid|tty)=\S*)){0,4}\s+ruser=<F-ALT_USER>\S*</F-ALT_USER>\s+rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=<F-USER>\S*</F-USER>)?%(__suff)s$
```

But this is rather a RE of `pam-generic` filter/jail, as already said in [issues/3189](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/3189), so it's not quite correct to use this for sshd jail (normally you'd see different messages in journal or auth.log).

Anyway to investigate deeper one needs the message example (or better the log-excerpt with all messages of sshd-session that caused ban).

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive answer !